# How do you make a pickaxe on Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I bought the app and started using it. I didn't know how to play so I started watching videos on youtube and saw that people automatically made a pickaxe so I tried making one and it doesn't let me! I used 3 wood planks and 2 sticks. Do I have to get a different type of wood?

Comment: The type of wood you use shouldn't matter.

Comment: So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a crafting table in order to make a pickaxe. "In-hand" crafting is not enough.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is kind of obvious, but when you're having trouble with crafting, restart the app. I do this all the time and it really helps. Other than that, make sure you have a crafting table, you have wood planks, and all the planks are the same type of wood.

Comment: While technically this answer is correct, it does not really add to what the accepted answer already says.